# Why would Xcode 6.3 beta debugger show that Swift NSData has a byte count of 190 but no properties?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In Xcode 6.3 beta running Swift 1.2 I have seemingly successfully retrieved a JSON object from an API, but the debugger is claiming that the object has no properties. The API is running on localhost and is called like this:

```
  NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest( request, queue: queue,
    completionHandler: completionHandler )
```

`completionHandler` is a closure with a breakpoint in it:

```
let completionHandler =
{
  ( response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError! ) -> Void in
  // BREAKPOINT HERE
}
```

The debugger shows that in Xcode 6.3 beta with Swift 1.2 **data: NSData!** is an ObjectiveC.NSObject of 190 bytes but with no properties, which seems flatly contradictory. I simply want the JSON data that I hope is hidden somewhere in those bytes. I do not know whether the debugger, or code that needs updating for Swift 1.2, or my understanding of things, or something else is to blame. I simply want the JSON.

**Post-script**

The JSON data was there all along, as the byte count suggested, and getting it was very simple (using SwiftyJSON):

```
let json = JSON( data: data )
```

Quite what has happened to the properties in the Xcode 6.3 beta debugger remains a mystery though. I'm not adding this as an answer to my own question, because whilst it **works** it might not necessarily be the **answer**. I am too new to Swift to know what the actual answer might be, or even if there is one.

Comment: What's the actual problem?  Which results are you expecting?  Is the 6.3 version not working as intended?  If so, can we remove all of the stuff about Xcode 6.2, and make this question more focused with a better explanation of what the problem actually is?

Comment: Edited. It is possible to point out weaknesses without getting [passive-]aggressive nhgrif, we are all just trying to get along here. MJB.

Comment: I'm not being passive-aggressive.  I'm pointing out the concerns.  Your question is unclear.  I've voted to close it as such.  Your question is about the Xcode 6.3 version, correct?  So cut out all of the Xcode 6.2 stuff.  It's only relevant so far as to say "This worked in 6.2, but now it does not work in 6.3".  Then, clarify more your exact problem.  Is the object simply being intrepreted incorrectly by the debugger (but you're still able to use it correctly)?  Or are actually getting the wrong type of object returned from the method?

Comment: I apologise for my lack of clarity. I feel that the 6.2 data is relevant because it shows what *should* be there, presumably *is* there given that both examples show a byte count of 190, but is somehow *not* there. Instead there is an NSObject with a value of (None), which is not useful. I presumed the image with (None) would describe the problem without me having to be ungraciously blunt about it. I was wrong, I apologise. I accept you weren't being passive-agressive, perhaps you could formulate your words in such a way as that does not become a possible interpretation in future?

Comment: Thank you for your input anyway nhgrif, I appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Your problem should be made as clear as possible with words (for lots of reasons, but primarily to help search results and identifying duplicates).  The pictures can help make the problem more clear, but they should never be used as a substitute.  And your question is **definitely** not clear in terms of whether the problem is strictly with the debugger, or if the wrong object is *actually* returned.  Is the problem with Xcode debugger, or with the framework?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance re: images, will bear in mind. If I knew the problem to your final question nhgrif, I probably wouldn't be on here asking questions. I don't know, in short, I would simply like my data. I am still trying to find that balance between lengthy, detailed posts that nobody reads because they are lengthy and detailed, and snappy posts that are too vague. What we want are snappy, detailed posts that don't read like they were written by lonely, angry men, but I'm not that good a writer.

Comment: ... I am asking you.  What happens if you try to use your `data` variable as an `NSData` object?  Are you getting an exception?  Is the code working?  Or have you actually tried the code?  Or did you just put a breakpoint to see what the debugger reports it as?  If you can't use the `data` variable as an `NSData` object, then the problem is with the framework.  You need to post some more text-based details (what exception is happening, etc).  If the problem is only that the debugger displays it incorrectly, then you need to edit your question and demonstrate the problem more clearly.

Comment: Thank you nhgrif. I don't know [yet]. I will investigate to see if I can come answer some of your questions. Thanks for your time, I do appreciate it, even if perhaps it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: OK nhgrif, looking for answers to your questions meant I found the answer to mine. Thank you for your time, sorry for being so windy. Maybe go ahead and delete this "question" now like you wanted to? I can't see it being of any use to anyone.

Comment: You can always delete your own question (as it has no answers with upvotes).  Or, it might make sense to post a self-answer (but if you do, post some more of the necessary details in the question itself).

Answer (score 2):

NSData is an encapsulation of the raw data bytes, before it's translated into a string or parsed as JSON.

If you want to see what this data contains, then you can use NSJSONSerialization (`let jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil)`)

and then read the dictionary like any other: `let value = jsonDictionary["key"]`

I hope that's helpful.